# How to use "rather" as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

> The instructions were rather complicated.

As an adverb, does 'rather' truly mean "fairly" or "to some degree" every single time?

Comment: Why do you say it's an adverb? It's clearly an intensifier like _very_

Answer (score 1):

In the 'modifier of adjective' sense, **rather** is used in conflicting ways:

> *rather*:  relatively or fairly; somewhat
>
> - *it's rather dull*

[[the above reference, Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rather)]

> *rather* 1: to a fairly large degree
>
> - *some* rather nice *chocolate biscuits* ... [I'd expect this perhaps to be stressed; EA]
> - *I realize that I’ve been rather stupid and selfish.*

There are corresponding 'modifier of comparative adjective' and 'modifier of adverb' usages:

> - *The problem is rather more complicated than we had expected.*
> - *Matt left rather suddenly without any explanation.*

But there is also another perhaps conflicting sense:

> *rather* 1a [mainly in speech] a little too much, or to a degree that is slightly too great
>
> - *Don’t you think she’s rather young to be travelling abroad on her own?*
> - *It’s a good essay, but rather long.*
>
> rather too: *Toby had drunk rather too much*.

[[Macmillan Dictionary; adjusted](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/rather)]

Comment: Thorough and not long. That sweet spot.